# Duplicate entry '111-222' for key 'PRIMARY' when inserting a new value to MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table running on [AWS RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/rds/) with structure like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `col1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `col2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `f_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col1`,`col2`),
  KEY `idx_col1` (`col1`),
  KEY `idx_col2` (`col2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col1=111 AND col2=222;
```

returns 0 row.

But when I run an insert query

```
INSERT INTO my_table 
        (col1, col2, f_name, l_name) 
VALUES (111, 222, 'John', 'Doe')
```

I got an error saying

> Duplicate entry '111-222' for key 'PRIMARY'.

Why does this happen? The table doesn't contain a row with col1=111 and col2=222.

There's already a row with values `col1`=111, `col2`=111, `f_name`='John', and `l_name`='Doe'. But I don't think this would cause a duplicate entry error.

=========================== EDIT ======================================

There's a trigger that generates the duplicate error. Here's the script to reproduce the error.

```
# Initialize the tables
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `col1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `col2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `f_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col1`,`col2`),
  KEY `idx_col1` (`col1`),
  KEY `idx_col2` (`col2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `triggered_table` (
  `col1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `col2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `update_date` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col1`,`col2`),
  KEY `idx_col1` (`col1`),
  KEY `idx_col2` (`col2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

# Insert the data that cause duplicate error
INSERT INTO triggered_table (col1, col2) VALUES (111, 222);

# Create the trigger
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER weird_trigger AFTER INSERT
 ON my_table
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO triggered_table 
    (col1, col2) 
    VALUES (NEW.col1, NEW.col2);
END$$
DELIMITER ;

# Create the duplicate error
INSERT INTO my_table 
        (col1, col2, f_name, l_name) 
VALUES (111, 222, 'John', 'Doe');
```

I really don't understand why the developers created the `triggered_table` table. Why didn't they put `update_date` column to `my_table`?

This is so weird.

Comment: This is not reproducible, could you have a corrupt index on your primary key?

Comment: Are those the actual values that produce the error or 111 and 222 are just examples?

Comment: 111 and 222 are just examples.

Comment: Did the actual values contain leading zeros? Does the query return 1 row if you add quotes around 111 and 222?

Comment: @DaleBurrell It's not related to `sql-server`. I've deleted the tag.

Comment: Since its now `VARCHAR`, quote the numbers and try again.

Comment: @SalmanA Both of the actual values do not contain leading zeros.

Comment: @SalmanA The actual type of `col1` and `col2` are `int(11)`. I've modified my question to reflect the actual column type.

Comment: @Brian Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of your problem. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions and provide the necessary SQL scripts to reproduce this error (including the mentioned trigger after the INSERT query).

Comment: @Progman, I've attached a script to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

`Truncate` your table then run (Assuming that you have only a test data but if not, you have to do some backup first)

```
INSERT INTO my_table 
        (col1, col2, f_name, l_name) 
VALUES (111, 222, 'John', 'Doe')
```

Now if the error still exists, this is a pretty much problem.

Your error seems like you concatinated col1 and col2 as your primary key (`'111-222'`)

You can try 
`select * from yourTable where FieldPrimary = '111-222'` if it is already exists

Comment: Can you explain what might happen under the hood? Is this problem caused by any type of cache mechanisms?

Comment: Yeah i understand @Brian need to just simulate the issue.

Comment: This problem happens on a production database. I'll have to do a lot of preparations before truncating the table.

Comment: Yeah that is a big problem. I'm just giving you an idea.

Comment: What should I put in `FieldPrimary`? I mean `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE FieldPrimary = '111-222';` doesn't work. `FieldPrimary` must be replaced by other values.

Comment: Replace it your real field name.

Comment: I think you have a trigger concatinating col1 and col2 as your `primaryfield value` just a guess. that is why you got this error.

Comment: you are right. There's a trigger that got triggered after an insert operation on `my_table`. This is the root cause for this problem.

Comment: then you cannot no longer run that Insert Script with `111,222` unless you have to remove the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate key error does not come from the `my_table` table but from the `triggered_table` table instead. When you add a row in `triggered_table` for the key `(111, 222)` and then add a new row in the `my_table` table (with the same key), your trigger will also try to add  a new row with the key `(111, 222)` in your `triggered_table`. However there is already such a key in use and you will get the duplicate key error.

Depending on what you want to do with the `my_table` and `triggered_table` tables, you might want to change the trigger to use `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`. Or you run a check with `SELECT` first to see if you need to add a new row or not. After that you can run an `UPDATE` query to change the value of `update_date`. But to answer your question, the duplicate key error comes from the duplicate key in the `triggered_table` table.